# Hot reload of Node.js Typescript in Docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I will start by saying, if I run without using Docker, then hot reload works.  This makes me think that I probably have nodemon and ts-node configured correctly.

After getting Node.js 20.x and Postgresql 15 installed, my `Dockerfile` is ends with this:

```
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY nodemon.json ./
COPY . .

CMD npm install && npm run start:dev
```

`compose.yaml` is as follows:

```
services:
  server:
    container_name: stoopid
    build: .
    image: base
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/home/node/app/src
```

My .ts files are all in ./src on the development computer.

I run `docker compose build` and then `docker compose up -d` to start the container.  If I make changes locally, the server doesn't restart in Docker, even though it appears that the changed file is in the container.

What am I missing when I am trying to get the hot reload working in the Docker container?  Note that I am using Docker Compose V2 (hence `docker compose` rather than `docker-compose`).

Comment: Can you split install from start? `RUN npm install` `CMD npm run start:dev`. That won't change much, but it's recommended

Comment: I recommend trying `tsx watch` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx ) instead of `nodemon` + `ts-node`

Comment: If you are trying to develop inside containers, consider using VSCde DevContainer (basically editing those files in your repo directly from inside Docker)

Comment: If you have a working non-Docker setup, why not use that; what are you hoping to gain by adding Docker and its isolation features into your setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze  Docker will be more helpful when I finally get around to using the database.

Answer (score 0):

From your Dockerfile, remove the line

```
COPY . .
```

This is because you have copied your source code into the image, and nodemon inside the docker container cannot detect the changes in the attached volume. Removing this line will remove the copied source code and nodemon should work

You can refer to a [gist I created here](https://gist.github.com/kennysliding/5e872ada25f3ca84b9f96281fe48a716), this is a working example I put together

Comment: If you don't `COPY` the code into the image, how does it know what to run? If you're totally dependent on the code existing on the host, why not just use Node on the host system without Docker?

Comment: You are using the `volumes` field in the docker compose file to attach the codebase to the docker image and that's how it knows what to run. I agree with your second point but there's also some benefits to it, for example, if you would like to develop your code on a certain platform that isn't the same as your computer OS, and this is StackOverflow, my answer is a response to OP's question, but not a question to why he would do this a certain way.